# Python Kivy: Problem with dynamically assigning widget ids

Tags: python, user-interface, kivy

Im writing an app in Kivy which automaticaly adds Buttons and gives them a unique id using a for loop. This id is then used as a key in the dictionary for a link. So the dictionary works fine and after printing it, it outputs `{'button0': 'somewebsite', 'button1': 'other website', 'button2': 'andanotherwebsite'}` which is exactly what I want but the button `callback` function always prints out `button2` instead of its own id. Am I assigning the ids wrong? The example below demonstrates my problem.

```py
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivymd.utils import asynckivy
from kivy.clock import Clock


class TestButton(Button):
    def callback(self):
        print(self.id)


class RootWidget(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.links = ["somewebsite", "other website", "andanotherwebsite"]
        self.dic_btn_to_lnk = {}
        
        self.size_hint = (None, None)
        self.size = ("600dp", "50dp")
        Clock.schedule_once(self.add_widgets, 0)

    def add_widgets(self, *args):
        async def update():
            number = 0
            for link in self.links:
                button = TestButton()

                button.text = link
                button.size = ("200dp", "50dp")
                button.pos_hint = {"center_x": .5}

                btn_id = "button" + str(number)
                button.id = btn_id
                button.bind(on_release=lambda x: button.callback())
                number += 1

                self.dic_btn_to_lnk[btn_id] = link

                self.add_widget(button)

                print(self.dic_btn_to_lnk)
        asynckivy.start(update())


class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return RootWidget()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your `on_release` binding is calling `button.callback()`, and `button` will be the last `Button` added by the time the `on_release` is triggered. The solution is to use `partial`, which freezes its arguments to their values when `partial` is executed, so the `on_release` calls the correct `button.callback`. Like this:

```
button.bind(on_release=partial(button.callback))
```

And to simplify the above, the definition of `callback` is changed to:

```
class TestButton(Button):
    def callback(self, instance):
        print(self.id)
```

Comment: I din't know, `partial` before and your post make me search about it, thanks. But I don't understand how `partial` is useful is this case? I just replaced his bind call by `button.bind(on_release=button.callback)` and change  `callback` as you suggest  and it work fine.